# tracepc nouveau on Ubuntu installation

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, nouveau

I was trying to install ubuntu on laptop, which has windows 11 and Nvidia Geforce.So i created a live USB and came to the point where I was asked try ubuntu or install it.I clicked on try and it gave me a black screen with several lines having tracepc nouveau.I then held the power button to switch off the laptop.Currently my laptop has windows and it seems to work fine.

In my old laptop, I had ubuntu , which I downloaded and it worked correctly.

So I dont understand the issue in the current installation.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu exactly did you try?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to boot it with "nomodeset"?

> try modifying the boot parameters. At the initial black screen menu, press “e” to edit the boot options. Replace the words “quiet splash” with “nomodeset” and then press ctrl-x or F10 to boot.

Comment: Where is the quoted text from? Can you [edit] your post and add the source? Also, can you explain a bit why `nomodset` would help? This would make your answer much helpful. Thanks!